# Qt Creator 5.6 how to speed up compilation with large number (3000+) of widgets in one project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5.6

I'm implementing a qt windows desktop app which has 30+ views. I use a QStackedwidget with 100+ pages in it. And each page contains 100+ QWdiget.

Now, when I compile my project, Qt Creator 5.6 (with jom/msvc2013) takes 30+ minutes on my MacBook Pro 2013 (i5, 8G, Windows 10). When compilation, the CPU usage of 
Microsoft C/C++ Compiler Driver is about 35%, and Memory usage is about 400MB.

**Does it make sense to take so long to compile my project? Is there any way to speed it up without updating my hardware?**

Thanks

Comment: If your widgets are common, or if you could somehow join similar ones, you can use `.setEnabled(true/false)` and some function deciding the order and appearance. If not...

Comment: I bet what's taking that long is the Qt meta-code generator. Other than parallelizing compilation and improving your code structure (with less includes and more forward-declaration), I don't think you stand a chance in improving this much. But still, if you could improve this by a factor of 3, that isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried telling qmake to use more cpu cores? The Core i5 has 4 cores so you can set:

```
set MAKEFLAGS=-j4
```

Alternatively if you want it to be dynamic you could try this variable (that I've read about but not used myself):

```
set MAKEFLAGS=-j%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%
```